# passing static variables to a function

Tags: c#, multithreading, static

i have the following global variables

```
private static Queue<List<object>> webdata1Queue = new Queue<List<object>>();
private static Queue<List<object>> webdata2Queue = new Queue<List<object>>();
public static DataTable products1;
public static DataTable products2;
```

and this function

```
private void Downloader(Queue<List<object>> webdataQueue,Datatable products)
        {
        }
```

is this the right way to pass static variables to a function? i need to pass the declared variables because i will be using the same function with 2 different threads.

Comment: yes , but if you have critical section than protect it

Comment: @Saurabh but i mean when i pass it like this, does it get passed by its adress in the memory, or another copy of the variable is made in someother place?

Comment: all objects are passed by reference in c#

Comment: @fenix2222, object's address is passed by value, Not really pass by reference, since you can't assign null to the object in a method. See [Parameter passing in C# by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: its just that i wat to treat them as global variables without having to write the function twice!, so which one of you is right?!by default ref or value?!

Comment: If you are going to assign null to that variable or initialize it inside method then it wont work, but you can pass it like you are doing if you are just modifying properties of it and adding items to list.

Comment: @fenix2222 nop i will be just locking them and using Enqueue, will never set it to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to assign null to that variable or initialize it inside method then it wont work, but you can pass it like you are doing if you are just modifying properties of it and adding items to list.